# Not able to install OpenAm, throwing org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.ConstraintViolationException: Object Class Violation

Tags: openam, opendj

I am using java 8 to run, but getting the following exception when trying out with default/custom mode of OpenAm installation in installation logs.

```
The lower level exception message
Object Class Violation: Entry ou=dashboardService,ou=services,dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org violates the Directory Server schema configuration because it does not include a structural objectclass. All entries must contain a structural objectclass
The lower level exception:
org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.ConstraintViolationException: Object Class Violation: Entry ou=dashboardService,ou=services,dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org violates the Directory Server schema configuration because it does not include a structural objectclass. All entries must contain a structural objectclass
at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LdapException.newLdapException(LdapException.java:176)
at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.spi.ResultLdapPromiseImpl.setResultOrError(ResultLdapPromiseImpl.java:142)
at org.forgerock.opendj.grizzly.LDAPClientFilter$ClientResponseHandler.addResult(LDAPClientFilter.java:126)
at org.forgerock.opendj.io.LDAPReader.readAddResult(LDAPReader.java:173)
at org.forgerock.opendj.io.LDAPReader.readProtocolOp(LDAPReader.java:571)
at org.forgerock.opendj.io.LDAPReader.readMessage(LDAPReader.java:132)
at org.forgerock.opendj.grizzly.LDAPBaseFilter.handleRead(LDAPBaseFilter.java:82)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue, when checked logs of tomcat server, there was some right issue to the user which denied it from creating 'temp' folder inside tomcat. I guess OpenAm installation is using this folder internally during configuration. My issue got resolved when created a 'temp' folder manually inside tomcat server. If anyone gets this error, **please check your tomcat logs first to resolve the issue.**